# When converting markdown to latex with pandoc, how can I end a block before the next heading?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, beamer

I am trying to put one sentence on a slide (written in markdown and translated to latex/beamer with pandoc) in a block without also including the following sentence. The only thing I can find in markdown that corresponds to a block is a heading, but that doesn't work for my use case, since it always extends to the start of the next heading of the same level or higher. Here is a minimal example:

```markdown
# Example slide

Here is an example slide.

## Block

This should be within the block.

This shouldn't be within the block.
```

This produces the following latex output:

```latex
[preamble omitted]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example slide}
\protect\hypertarget{example-slide}{}
Here is an example slide.

\begin{block}{Block}
\protect\hypertarget{block}{}
This should be within the block.

This shouldn't be within the block.
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way I can "end" the scope implicitly created by the heading? Alternatively, is there another syntactic construct I can use to create a beamer block that I can end at will?

What I tried:

1. Adding a paragraph (doesn't end the block)
2. Adding a pause (doesn't end the block)
3. Adding an empty heading (creates a new block)

Comment: can you try https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2957#issuecomment-340855258 ?

Comment: @AxelKemper No luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example show by @jgm at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2957#issuecomment-340855258 you could use divs:

```
# Example slide

Here is an example slide.

::: {.block}
## Block

This should be within the block.
:::

This shouldn't be within the block.
```